# What are the advantages of the DataMember attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, datamember

What is the exact advantages of the DataMember attribute? What is the difference between a serialized Field and a Field with the DataMember attribute. A friend told there is some performance wise gains?

EDIT:
Consider this example:

```
[Serializable] 
public class MyObject { 
public int num; 
public String str; 
}

public class MyObject { 
[DataMember]
public int num; 
[DataMember]
public String str; 
}
```

Comment: [`[DataMember]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) allows for opt-in serialization of fields in the data contract serialization model. The only impact on performance I can think of is that serialization will take more time if there are more fields to serialize, so you may want to avoid serializing fields you do not need.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? The one for the DataMember attribute clearly saying what it is for?

Comment: Not just considered - been there done that. Let me elaborate on my question. See edit.